# Not able to set header to AMQP Message using MessageProperties

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp

The below code shows how I am setting header and message type to AMQP message.

```
MessageProperties properties = new MessageProperties();
    properties.setHeader("KEY", "HOUSE");
    properties.setContentType(MessageProperties.CONTENT_TYPE_JSON);
Message message = new Message("1234567;Branch A;SALES;3000.50;Pending approval".getBytes(), properties);
rabbitTemplate.sendAndReceive("", QUEUE_NAME, message);
```

After sending the message in the queue, the message is received by Transformer.

```
@Transformer(inputChannel = "inboundChannel", outputChannel = "toutboundChannel")
public Property buildProperty(Message<String> property){
    LOGGER.info("message received :: HEADERS: {}, PAYLOAD :{}", property.getHeaders(), property.getPayload());
....
}
```

In the logs, the header "KEY: HOUSE" is missing and even the message type is not JSON and "text/plain" instead.

```
LOGS:
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] INFO com.demo.maven.spring.integration.endpoint.TransformerRequestBuilder - message received :: HEADERS: {amqp_receivedRoutingKey=mobile.queue, amqp_deliveryTag=2, amqp_replyTo=amq.rabbitmq.reply-to.g2dkABByYWJiaXRAbG9jYWxob3N0AAAW9QAAAAAD.tTIFOS2gsM7qIlGYaybfrg==, amqp_deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_redelivered=true, id=399dda4f-4ba1-7cf4-2310-03dbfbac82b6, contentType=text/plain, timestamp=1421649922840}, PAYLOAD :1234567;Branch A;SALES;3000.50;Pending approval
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `MessagePropertiesBuilder` class is for that.
2. By default Spring Integration AMQP Inbound Endpoint (`AmqpInboundChannelAdapter` and `AmqpInboundGateway`) maps only standard AMQP headers. That's is a default behaviour of `DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper`. To accept any user-specofic headers you should inject `AmqpHeaderMapper` (`setHeaderMapper`) to that inbound endpoint with an option `setRequestHeaderNames("*")`. Or provide full list of names of desired custom headers.
3. Re. `contentType=text/plain`: I think something between AMQP Inbound Endpoint and that `@Transformer(inputChannel = "inboundChannel"` overrides the received from AMQP `contentType` header. Because `RabbitTemplate` doesn't do that, if you send `Message` not any other Object. Please, share `DEBUG` logs for the `org.springframework.integration` category for the message receiver. Of course we need that part of logs, when you receive message till that `@Transformer`

Comment: Thanks Artem Bilan. This worked.
Even the contentType is displaying the changes now :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

This will work, you have to build the messageproperties correctly.

```
MessageProperties properties = new MessageProperties();
    properties.builder()
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    //headers here
    .headers(Map<String, Object>)
    .build();
```

Comment: I am using    org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageProperties.
There is no builder() or build() method in it.

Comment: If you are talking about build.. I tried the below code as well



MessagePropertiesBuilder builder = MessagePropertiesBuilder.newInstance();builder.setHeader("KEY", "HOUSE");
builder.setContentType(MessageProperties.CONTENT_TYPE_JSON);
MessageProperties properties = builder.build();
Message message = new Message("1234567;Branch A;SALES;3000.50;Pending approval".getBytes(), properties);

Still Same result as above.